# How long is two rolls of parchment within Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: analysis, harry-potter, the-prisoner-of-azkaban

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, whilst Professor Snape is covering for Professor Lupin, Snape sets an assignment to write **two rolls of parchment** on the werewolf and emphasises *recognising it*.

The students, including Mr. Potter, react as if he has set an essay of 7000 words. Something that would take a considerable amount of time. Two rolls of parchment suggests two sides of A4/letter size. Like the standard paper you find in a household printer. This would take, I guess, on average what...an hour..two, maximum?

Do we know of a more accurate dimension/size for ‘two rolls of parchment, considering the students reaction to the assignment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find a definitive answer for you, but the wizarding world tends to use more old-fashioned units and technologies.  [Foolscap folio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foolscap_folio) was the traditional writing paper size prior to the introduction of A4 in the UK.  Foolscap folio is 8.5 x 13.5 inches - almost two inches longer than A4 and certainly quite a bit longer than US Letter.

So two scrolls might be slightly more than 2 sides of A4 (or I guess 4 sides of A4 if they can write on both sides.)

I think the reaction of the students in this scene is more about Snape.  They've been used to having fun practical lessons with Lupin and now they have Snape as a substitute, a teacher they detest and distrust, who is giving them a boring written homework task.  Also they have to write these using quills on rough parchment not modern pens and paper, it might take longer for the same amount of words.